# Passing a parameter to an d3.svg.line var

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am using d3js v3 and I am trying to create a sparkline by calling a line function with a parameter. When I do this:

```
.attr("d", line)
```

I get a d attribute in my svg path element. But when I do:

```
.attr("d", function(d){line(d);})
```

the d attribute is not added to the dom. I have tried renaming the variable to something not used elsewhere in the script. It did not help.

My line function is this:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.t);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return d.v * -20;
    })
    .interpolate("basis")
;
```

My x and xAxis functions are here:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]).domain([t0, t1]).nice(),
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickFormat(customTimeFormat)
;
```

And for y I have:

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"])
    .range([0,-20,-40,-60,-80,-100,-120,-140,-160,-180])
;

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
;
```

If I add log statements, I can see that all functions are called as expected, and even when I log the output of line(d) to the console, I can see the complete "d" attribute as it should be, but it does not end up in the dom.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
.attr("d", line)
```

You are passing in `line` as a function reference which will be invoked as a callback and passed `d` as an argument.  The return value of this function will be assigned to the attribute.

When you do this:

```
.attr("d", function(d){line(d);})
```

You are passing your newly defined function in as a reference which will be invoked as a callback just like above.  It is the return value of this function that will be assigned to the attribute.  Because your function is invoking `line(d)` itself, you need to return its return value from your function:

```
.attr("d", function(d) { return line(d); })
```